# How we show primitive action shows alternating group

Tags: graph-theory, group-actions

I have a graph (as shown in figure), which represents a quotient of the group $$G=\langle A,B,C,D; A^3=B^2=C^3=D^2=(AC)^2=(AD)^2=(BC)^2=(BD)^2=1 \rangle.$$ I proved that $G$ acts 2-transitively and so primitively. I happen to know the permutation group of this graph is alternating group Alt(17), but how can I show theoretically that this graph represents Alt(17)?

[image]

Comment: I just want some hints or I need direction to work..

Comment: $G$ is definitely not isomorphic to Alt(17) (it is infinite, with derived factors: 2; 3; 2^6; Z^24 x 2^5; ...). The action of G on the cosets of $y$ is probably not Alt(17), but I haven't proven that. I'm not sure what the graph represents; lots of vertices are missing B edges.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this if a vertex is missing, it means that vertex is a loop or you can say fix point